# Как отключить комментарии в DLE везде, кроме блога?

Tags: php, dle

Как отключить комментарии в DLE везде, кроме блога?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В fullstory.tpl комментарии выводятся через тег `{comments}` . Нужно его в обернуть `[not-catlist=id нужной категории]` . Например если вы не хотите что бы форма комментариев выводилась в категории с id 5 то должно быть так

```
[not-catlist=5]{comments}[/not-catlist]
```

Так же можно указать несколько категорий через запятую

```
[not-catlist=5,6,7,8]{comments}[/not-catlist]
```